# problem for loading robot pr2 model

Tags: ros, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
while I try to Starting the Manipulation Pipeline. I just based on the following website:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting%20the%20Manipulation%20Pipeline

The step is:

1. rosmake pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch
2. roscore
3. export ROBOT=sim
4. roscd pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch
5. modify the pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
   just

-->

### Just make it connect as a client for object database running on remote server at Willow Garage
6 cd ~
7. roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
The I got the following information:
Mainly is said that :

[ERROR] [1329418027.455848865]: Robot model '/robot_description' not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?
[ WARN] [1329418027.463987029]: Models not loaded
[FATAL] [1329418027.466372646]: Could not load the xml from parameter server: robot_description

### [ERROR] [1329418027.466448443]: Could not load robot model. Are you sure the robot model is on the parameter server?

do I need more step to run this demo?
I am using ubuntu 11.04 or 10.04, 64 bit electric ros. The problems are the same.
Thanks for any help.
Best regards.
Zhenli

[ INFO] [1329418027.444594041]: waitForService: Service [/tabletop_object_recognition] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ERROR] [1329418027.455848865]: Robot model '/robot_description' not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?
[ WARN] [1329418027.463987029]: Models not loaded
[FATAL] [1329418027.466372646]: Could not load the xml from parameter server: robot_description

[ERROR] [1329418027.466448443]: Could not load robot model. Are you sure the robot model is on the parameter server?
[collider_node-11] process has died [pid 22887, exit code -11].
log files: /home/administrator/.ros/log/ff64f9c2-58cb-11e1-953f-18f46a4fafa8/collider_node-11*.log
respawning...
[collider_node-11] restarting process
process[collider_node-11]: started with pid [23024]
[ INFO] [1329418027.750126583]: Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] [1329418027.751014430]: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[FATAL] [1329418027.765071054]: Could not load the xml from parameter server: robot_description

[ERROR] [1329418027.765130414]: Could not load robot model. Are you sure the robot model is on the parameter server?
[ INFO] [1329418027.850490364]: Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] [1329418027.857919089]: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ERROR] [1329418027.871698784]: Robot model '/robot_description' not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?
[ WARN] [1329418027.875139906]: Models not loaded
[collider_node-11] process has died [pid 23024, exit code -11].
log files: /home/administrator/.ros/log/ff64f9c2-58cb-11e1-953f-18f46a4fafa8/collider_node-11*.log
respawning...
[collider_node-11] restarting process
process[collider_node-11]: started with pid [23157]
[FATAL] [1329418027.968994927]: Could not load the xml from parameter server: robot_description

[ERROR] [1329418027.969069875]: Could not load robot model. Are you sure the robot model is on the parameter server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27803/problem-for-loading-robot-pr2-model/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer by myself:
I should run pr2 simulator.
The steps:
1. roscore
2. export ROBOT=sim
3.roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
4. Here you also load the object table.cup
5. modify the pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch just

```
6. roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-08**:
Hi zhenli, I also have the same problem and my approach is quite similar to run this demo. I'm using ROS fuerte and Ubuntu LTS 12.04. But I used local database. However, the result gives some errrors and hanging: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error information:
Could not load the xml from parameter server: robot_description
Could not load robot model. Are you sure the robot model is on the parameter server?
Robot model '/robot_description' not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?
Models not loaded
Could not load the xml from parameter server: robot_description

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1